# Trouble with forward linked list

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I've implemented a backwards linked list successfully, but I'm trying to find out how to implement a forwards linked list, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  The problem is in my `insert` method.  I'm trying to keep track of the previous node, and point it to the newly created node, but I'm missing something.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next_node = new_next

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head

    def insert(self, data):
        previous_node = self.head
        current_node = self.head
        new_node = Node(data)
        if previous_node is not None:
            previous_node.set_next(new_node)
            previous_node = self.head
```

Comment: Why `previous_node = self.head` ? every node inserted after head?

Comment: You have a typo here `new_node = Node(data)` should be `new node = Node2(data)`, is it possible `Node` is calling your backwards linked list and causing the confusion?

Comment: You need a `while` with condtion that Kurt said in his answer , then add your `new_node` after the desired `previous_node`, Kurt answer is completly correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

If the list is empty, set the head, and return. Else, loop "forward" through all the elements until you hit a `None` node. Once you do, set the appropriate `next_node` value.

```
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head

    def empty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)    # Want to insert this
        if self.empty():         # Is this list empty?
            self.head = new_node #   Yes? Then add the head
        else:                    # No? There are elements in the list
            current_node = self.head                    # Save a moving reference
            while not current_node.get_next() is None:  # While there are forward nodes
                current_node = current_node.get_next()  # Move the reference forward
            current_node.set_next(new_node)             # Set the last node, thus inserting at the "end"
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what your `insert` method is supposed to do. If it is meant to insert at the beginning of the list (before head), then you should be setting `new_node.set_next(previous_node)` and `self.head = new_node`. If you meant to append to the end of the list, then you will need to scan through the list until you find the node with `current_node.get_next() == None` and do `current_node.set_next(new_node)`.

Since this looks like homework, I don't want to straight out give you the answer. I will provide some pseudocode to get you started though

```
def insert(value):
    let current = head
    until current.next_node == None:
        let current = current.next_node

    let current.next_node = Node2(value)
```

Comment: I can't figure out for the life of me how to implement this.  Would you be willing to add the correct `insert` method to your answer?

Comment: How can I check the `get_next()` of type `None`?

Comment: You don't. You need to stop one step before that, where `current_node.get_next() == None`.

Comment: Isn't `current` initialized to `None` before any nodes are added?

Comment: Yes you'll need to check for that special case first with an if-else statement. If you're still confused you can look at @cricket_007's answer where he wrote the code for you.

Comment: I've tried that code, and I get the same error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_next'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103775/discussion-between-kurt-stutsman-and-123).

Answer (score 0):

Let's write out what this does:

```
def insert(self, data):
    previous_node = self.head    # set to head of list
    current_node = self.head     # not used elsewhere
    new_node = Node(data)        # make a new node with the given data.
    if previous_node is not None:        # if the list isn't empty
        previous_node.set_next(new_node) #    point the list head to the new node
        previous_node = self.head        # does nothing; this was already the list head
```

Bottom line: this creates a new node and makes it the "next" node of the list head.  That's all this does; your list will never be more than 2 nodes long.  In fact, your list can't ever get a first node, because you have no code to insert into an empty list.

To fix this, you need a clear, adaptable algorithm, such as:

```
Create a new node.
Link the existing list behind the new node:
    Set new.next to the current head node.
    Point the list head to the new node.
```

Note that this works even with an empty list.

If you want a list that adds to the end, then also maintain a self.tail attribute that points to the last node in the list.  Then your insert (append) looks like this:

```
Create a new node.
Link the new node to the existing tail:
    if tail exists:
        Set tail.next to the new node.
    else:
        Set head to the new node
    Set tail to the new node.
```

Is this clear enough to implement?